# Vite: Prevent bundling the same dependency multiple times

Tags: npm, dependencies, vite, rollup

I have the following structure in project (I'm using npm):

- `app` imports: `lib1` and `lib2`.
- `lib2` imports: `lib1`.

After building `app` with Vite the resulting bundle has two instances of `lib1`.

This is causing problems for me since `app` and `lib2` cannot communicate with each other through `lib1` because each instance has its own global variables.

How do I tell Vite to use the same instance of `lib1` with both `app` and `lib2`?

---

**Edit**: Here is a test case to show my problem:

`lib1/index.js`:

```js
let x = 0;
export function test(name) {
  console.log(name, ++x);
}
```

`lib1/package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "lib1",
  "type": "module"
}
```

---

`lib2/index.js`:

```js
import { test } from 'lib1'

export function main() {
  test("LIB2");
}
```

`lib2/package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "lib2",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "lib1": "..."
  },
}
```

---

`app/index.js`:

```js
import { test } from 'lib1'
import { main } from 'lib2'

main();
test("APP");
```

`app/package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "app",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "lib1": "...",
    "lib2": "..."
  },
}
```

---

Vite is running the default configuration, I don't have a `vite.config.js`.

---

The output I'm expecting is:

```
LIB2 1
APP 2
```

The current output is:

```
LIB2 1
APP 1
```

Note: this is only happening when bundling with Vite for production using `vite build` command which is what I care about. When running Vite in development mode the behavior is as expected.

Note: The problem doesn't happen if `lib1` is imported in `package.json` as a file path. It has to be imported from NPM or GitHub to reproduce the problem.

Comment: without code (imports), file structure and vite.config.js hard to tell